# How get a currentScript attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How i get currentScript attributes?

*I am using this code to get the currentScript but this is not working because the script is async.

```
var target = document.currentScript || (function() {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  return scripts[scripts.length - 1];
})();
```

Sorry for the languages erros i am learning english.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.currentScript is perfectly working with chrome and FF, however, IE dose not support it. It is painful.

```
 scripts[scripts.length - 1];
```

Codes above are not trustable. It defers on async condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try listening to [beforescriptexecute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforescriptexecute) (untested):

```
document.addEventListener("beforescriptexecute", function(){
  var target = document.currentScript || (function() {
     var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
     return scripts[scripts.length - 1];
  })();
});
```

Comment: The link says it is a proprietary even specific to Gecko/Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `document.currentScript.async`?

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Comment: so, nklein i trying get a currentScript properties because is the only way to realy get a currentScript... the project has to be compatible with older browser(goddamm IE) and the 'currentScript' propertie is not suported in IE.

But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be not be executing during the DOM lifecycle point when document.currentScript actually has a value.  It only has a value on the initial execution of a script element.  As far as I know, script elements only execute at two different points in the document life cycle:

1. At load time, for script elements that are in the original HTML of the document
2. When a script element is *directly* inserted into a document

If a function in the script gets called at some other point, document.currentScript will either be null or it probably won't be the element you expect it to be (like if you insert a script element that calls a function in another script element).

I have found that using the jQuery $(...) with an html string generally gives me a null for document.currentScript.  As far as I know, if you need document.currentScript to be non-null when you insert a chunk of HTML, you can't use jQuery's html() method and you'll probably have to write your own.

Of course, if you just insert a chunk of HTML that *contains* script elements, they won't even execute because they're not being *directly* inserted.  So, your setHtml() function will have to *reinsert* each script element and you'll end up with code somewhat along these lines (example in CoffeeScript):

```
for script in $(el).find('script')
  if !script.type || script.type == 'text/javascript'
    newScript = document.createElement 'script'
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript'
    if script.src then newScript.src = script.src
    newScript.textContent = script.textContent
    script.parentNode.insertBefore newScript, script
    script.parentNode.removeChild script
```

If you want to handle script elements for other languages and you still want to take advantage of document.currentScript, you'll need to compile them to JavaScript and set newScript.textContent to the compiled code or else if you can only use an interpreter, you'll need to set newScript.textContent to a JavaScript expression you construct that calls the interpreter with script.textContent as a string.

Answer (score 0):

My attribute is 'param001'

```
async function getScriptParam(attr) 
{
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var currentScript = scripts[scripts.length-1];
        
        // in future, could just use the HTML5 standard dataset attribute instead: currentScript.dataset[attr]
        result=currentScript.getAttribute(attr); 
        return result
}

    
param001_b = getScriptParam('param001');    

console.log('msg646a: ', param001_b);
```

##################################

my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The script element</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript12312";
</script> 


<!--search in the file nestedarray_v1_browserify.js msg646></-->
<script src="nestedarray_v1_browserify.js" param001="param001_4453" param002="param002_434"></script>


</body>
</html>
```